# MVC ViewModel making use of a List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a view that makes use of a list and a string value.

Currently I am doing the following and passing it to the view:

```
var Note = (from p in db.tblNote where p.NoteName = pnote  select  p).ToList();
ViewBag.NotesID = id;

return PartialView(Note);
```

As you can see, currently I am passing the Note (which is a list) to the View and then will be getting the ViewBag directly in my view.

What I like to do is to create a viewmodel for this. 
I like to know what the best practice is to create a viewmodel for what I need.

Here is what I came up for the ViewModel :

```
public class NotesViewModel
{        
    public string NotesID { get; set; } // this will replace where I had ViewBag.NotesID

    public IEnumerable< Notes>  NotesList { get; set; } // this will replace where I had var Note = (from p in db.tblNote      
}
```

I am somewhat lost on where I create the Notes that you see in `IEnumerable<Notes>`, do I create another class called `Notes` in a different `.cs` file and how do I assign the appropriate type to it.
The  will represent the the LINQ Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want Notes to be a List of type Note? If so then why not just do `IEnumerable<Note>` ?

A `IEnumerable` is basically a generic data type that allows you to enumerate over its items, a List an extension of this.

So you would just change your code to be :-

```
public class NotesViewModel
{        

    public string NotesID { get; set; } // this will replace where I had ViewBag.NotesID

    public IEnumerable<Note>  NotesList { get; set; } // this will replace where I had var Note = (from p in db.tblNote

}

public ActionResult MyFunction()
{
    var Notes = (from p in db.tblNote where p.NoteName = pnote 
            select  p).ToList();

    var oMyNotesVM = new NotesViewModel();
    oMyNotesVM.NotesID = id;
    oMyNotesVM.NotesList = Notes;

    return PartialView(oMyNotesVM );
}
```

So here all we've done is take the List and passed it to IEnumerable since IEnumerable is a generic form of List. Basically for an item to impliment the IEnumerable it needs to support iteration through its datamembers.. for example

```
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  object obj = enumerator.Current;
  // work with the object
}
```

Which is the same (well almost as)

```
foreach(object obj in collection)
{
    // work with the object
}
```

If your asking what the datatype for `Note` should be then that would be the class type of db.tblNote. If this is entity framework then you could just use the class that was auto-generated from your model for this.

Comment: Thanks. I get the following message as it does not know what Note is in IEnumerable<Note> : Error 6 The type or namespace name 'Note' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am thinking I would need to create a class for Note so you it knows what it is

Comment: Are you using Entity Frameworks (or have a model pre-created) if so change the data-type Node to the class type of db.tblNote.

Comment: I am not sure MyNotesVM.NotesList = Notes;  is legal. I get Error 10 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.tblNote>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.tblNote>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Just cast it (IEnumerable<Models.tblNote>)

Comment: Thanks - it all works great. Question - instead of using IEnumerable, is there any thing else I can use (just curious). How about IList - what are the pros and cons?

Comment: IEnumerable is just a generic type, you could use List<T>. Have a look at the wiki entry on Data Structures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures You basically need to choose the right structure for the job.